# "AttributeError: module 'pip' has no attribute 'main'" when installing python libraries

Tags: python, visual-studio, pip, python-3.9

I have this problem with Python (*version 3.9*) and Visual Studio 2019.

```
AttributeError: module 'pip' has no attribute 'main'
```

Can anybody help me ?

Comment: Does it work with a production version of Python?

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO ! Please, add more information, context so that the community could help you. For instance, paste the commands you used to install the desired libraries.

Comment: ..and how is this related to Visual Studio? Did you install it using Visual Studio?

Comment: Note that Python3.9 is still in [alpha/beta development](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0596/#schedule). It is not yet a standard release version. Unless you are testing/developing your own modules to support the new Python version, I recommend using Python 3.8 or 3.7 instead.

Answer (score 1):

This problem might be because you are not using the latest version of pip, or because you did not upgrade correctly. Use the following command to upgrade. See [here](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5599) for more information.

```py
python3 -m pip install --user --upgrade pip==20.1
```